# Suggestions for replacing a Microsoft Natural Wireless Laser Mouse 6000

Tags: mouse, ergonomics

My partner uses a Microsoft Natural Wireless Laser Mouse 6000 (well actually, one that came with the keyboard and mouse combo...) and it's beginning to get weird on us (it drains batteries really fast, both good alkalines and rechargables). We'd replace it with another, but Microsoft seem to have discontinued the product.

Can anyone recommend a similar styled 'ergonomic' mouse? Ideally rechargeable, or with long battery life.

I use a Logitech Performance Mouse M950, which she finds isn't tilted enough and set off her wrists, and the 3M joystick mice go too far and set of her elbows and shoulders.

Here's the support page for it: http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/natural-wireless-laser-mouse-6000

Comment: You might also want to have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132/mouse-for-programmer?rq=1

Comment: This is not programming related.

Comment: Some programmers are mouse users too.

Comment: @gentlesea and some programmer drink beer too. Can I then ask beer-related questions here too?

Comment: @BartKiers: I would not mind...

Comment: We've started using Eneloop batteries in the mouse, and that's helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can still get this mouse as part of a keyboard/mouse package:
http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/natural-ergonomic-desktop-7000

Comment: Yes, that's being considered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In our company we evaluated some ergonomic mice and our favorite is the [Evoluent VerticalMouse 4](http://www.evoluent.com/vm4r.htm).

Comment: Yes, we looked at those, but they suffer the same issue as the 3M stick mouse and rotate her hand too far.